# php artisan package:discover --ansi There are no commands defined in the "package" namespace

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade

After upgrading Laravel from v6 to v8. Everything works but the artisan command that are run at the end of composer update

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

                                                         
There are no commands defined in the "package" namespace.  
                                                         

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Searched everywhere,  tried clearing bootstrap cache, still same problem persists..

Any one here with a fix?

Comment: How did you update from Laravel 6 to 8? Running `composer dump-autoload` is always a good first step to take.

Comment: When I do composer dump-autoload, I get the exact same error above, also when I do php artisan list, my list of commands is now very limited, it does not have all the commands that you have in regular install

Comment: @miken32 I upgraded it first  to 7 then I upgraded it to version 8, everything worked and the   project works, but the artisan commands do not work

Comment: HOW did you update it? Edit your question to include the steps you took.

Comment: Doesn't matter now, I installed it from scratch and just transferred the files. Thanks for attempting to help me @miken32

Comment: Ok if you don't have an answer for your question you can just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was caused by **disabled ConsoleSupport service provider in app config**, so enabling it fixed the issue:

```
# config/app.php
// ...
    'providers' => [
        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        // ...
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        // ...
    ]
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Could not solve the problem through upgrading the versions, and just installed it from scratch and moved the files and it worked.